# bootstrap 4 carousel won't shrink to fit view port

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to web development, self taught for a year, and recently started the udacity nanodegree program. I'm building a web page using bootstrap 4 and I would like to use the carousel as the header but the carousel is won't shrink to the viewport or screen size the images are much larger than desired especially on desktop.

Code source https://github.com/djneill/mbbjj?files=1

Demo page http://dninstalls.com/blankbootstrap/

```
    /*Carousel CSS */

    .carouselHeader{background: #655e5d}

    .carousel {
        background-color: red;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .carousel,.item,.active {
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-item {
        margin: auto;
        background: no-repeat center center scroll;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
        background: no-repeat center center scroll;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    <!--    Carousel Header -->
    <header id="carouselHeader" class="page-header">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide mastheads" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!--                    Carousel image 1 -->
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbbj%20kids.png" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <!--                    Carousel image 2 -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbjj%20kids2.png" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <!--                    Carousel image 3 -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbjj%20adult.png" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
                <!--                    Carousel image 4 -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbjj%20comp.png" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: You can set your `div#carouselExampleIndicators` a `max-width: 1000px;`, so you will limit the width...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust carousel wrapper height to reduced its height. This is the most easy and quick way. You can do it as following:

```
.carousel{
    max-height: calc(100vh - 81px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here, `81px` is header's height. So you can adjust that accordingly.

Comment: This has brought the carousel size down perfectly, the images are showing much larger than they actually are largest is 800 * 600. The carousel now fits the screen at all sizes

Answer (score 0):

Uneven image height is main problem in this carousel.

Firtsofall your image size is too large, If you want to use the same image with high resolution just give the height for carousel wrapper or else you can set the height for the image by using the image class (d-block w-100).

For best result just resize it using photo edit tool(Photoshop)

Comment: images have the d-block w-100 class, largest image size is 800 * 600 px it's like the bootstrap settings have a mind of their own